# DeviceTwin timestamps

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10

*I submitted [UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync doesn't update the Device Twin timestamps](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/609) in azure-iot-sdk-csharp's github, but I wonder if maybe I just don't know something and I decided to ask here as well.*

Is there documentation explaining when IoT Hub Device Twin's `statusUpdateTime`, `connectionState`, and `lastActivityTime` are updated?

---

My problem:

I have a device that periodically updates reported properties using `DeviceClient`'s `UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync` but the timestamps stay empty:

```
"statusUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"connectionState": "Connected",
"lastActivityTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there documentation explaining when IoT Hub Device Twin's
>   statusUpdateTime, connectionState, and lastActivityTime are updated?

You can reference "[Device identity properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-identity-properties)" part.

[image]

> I have a device that periodically updates reported properties using
>   DeviceClient's UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync but the timestamps stay
>   empty:

It seems an issue of old SDK and it has already been fixed. I use Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.18.0, it works for me. You can have a try.

```
            TwinCollection reportedProperties = new TwinCollection();
            reportedProperties["DateTimeLastDesiredPropertyChangeReceived"] = DateTime.Now;

            await deviceClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(reportedProperties).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I'm using 1.18.0 too. I would have thought that this would be set by the server side anyway.